# Expand views on changing orientation and screen size in auto layout

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have a UIImageView which I need to expand (height and width) on changing orientation and screen size. I am using auto layout constraints for that.

```
    topImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    topImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    topImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    topImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    topImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    if(login_DO.logoPath)
        [topImageView loadImage:login_DO.logoPath];

    [self.view addSubview:topImageView];

    NSArray *horizontalConstraints =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-(%i)-[topImageView(%f)]",X_OFFSET,VIEW_FRAME_WIDTH-X_OFFSET*2]
                                            options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"topImageView": topImageView}];

    NSArray *verticalConstraints =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-(%f)-[topImageView(80)]",navHeight]
                                            options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"topImageView": topImageView}];

    [self.view addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
    [self.view addConstraints:verticalConstraints];    

    NSLayoutConstraint *leadingMarginForImageConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                 constraintWithItem:topImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeadingMargin
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:self.view attribute:
                                                 NSLayoutAttributeLeadingMargin multiplier:1.0 constant:X_OFFSET];

    NSLayoutConstraint *topMarginForImageConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                           constraintWithItem:topImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTopMargin
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:self.view attribute:
                                                           NSLayoutAttributeTopMargin multiplier:1.0 constant:VIEW_FRAME_WIDTH-X_OFFSET*2];

    [self.view addConstraints:@[ leadingMarginForImageConstraint,
                                 topMarginForImageConstraint]];
```

But the image is not expanding. I am new to auto layouts. Am I missing any constraint?

Comment: Any comments or answers ?

Comment: your constraint is invalid _______________
suppose x = 10; width = 300; _______________
left = -x ; width >= -300. _______________
same with height its like your are flipping image in width and height . _______________
explain more what you are trying to achieve .. will add a answer accordingly .

Comment: add a screen-short.. for explaining if possible .

Comment: @rahul_send89 : I am trying to expand the UIImageView when the screen size changes. Say for example I run the application on iPad, in that case the UIImageView should expand.

Comment: ok .. if possible .. can u give a screen grab of what u want . so that i can change my answer .. ! it just your topMargin is conflicting with verticalConstraints and leadingMargin with horizontalConstraints..

Comment: u can also explain using ..
(view.width>320 && view.width<=superview.width) ..
(view.height>320 && view.width<=superview.height) ..
(view.x<=10(Margin||Padding) && (view.y<=10(Margin||Padding) ..
or view should be left or right from main screen left || right || bottom || top..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can change the imageBottomConstraint  from -navHeight to some other value from bottom. 
avoid using VIEW_FRAME_WIDTH cause it change when you change orientation.

```
UIView *superview = self.view;
 NSLayoutConstraint *imageTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                  constraintWithItem:topImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:navHeight];
    NSLayoutConstraint *imageBottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                     constraintWithItem:topImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:-navHeight];
    NSLayoutConstraint *imageLeftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                   constraintWithItem:topImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview attribute:
                                                   NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:X_OFFSET];
    NSLayoutConstraint *imageRightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                    constraintWithItem:topImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview attribute:
                                                    NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:-X_OFFSET];
[superview addConstraints:@[imageBottomConstraint ,
                            imageLeftConstraint, imageRightConstraint,
                            imageTopConstraint]];
```

for more help check http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_auto_layouts.htm

or try using https://github.com/marcoarment/CompactConstraint

let me know if it helped.

Comment: Can you please see my related question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228825/auto-layout-for-iphone-and-ipad. I think that is what I really want. I will edit this question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following code that adds an `ImageView` with Globe.png and add constraints so it appears as you describe. The difference is just to pinch all side edges to the superview (`self.view`) and then assign the constraints to the superview:

```
-(void)addImageView{
    topImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Globe.png"]]; // Added test image
    topImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    topImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    topImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    topImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    topImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:topImageView];

    NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:topImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:topImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:topImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:topImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

    [self.view addConstraints:@[topConstraint, bottomConstraint, leftConstraint, rightConstraint]];  //Note constraints are added to the superView
}
```