# Auto layout constraint for different screen size

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have the following constraint :

```
self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-(>=%f,<=%f)-[topImageView(>=120,<=170)]-|",navHeight,navHeight+40] options:0 metrics:0 views:viewsDictionary]];
```

When I run this on iPad, it seems fine. The view is **navHeight+40** from top. but when I run it on iPhone, it is still **navHeight+40** from top and not **navHeight**. Same goes for height.

Comment: how r u calculating navHeight..?
self.navigationBar.frame.size.height || self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height.... ?

Comment: can u share the dimension of image which you are using in your code.

Comment: navHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height

Comment: can check and NSLog the height is !=0 ..
and its >=40.

Comment: and if its <40 use  self.navigationBar.frame.size.height instead .

Comment: Do I have to set priority ?

Comment: iOS 7 and> have problem calculating Navigation height .
try testing with both.
and please provide your image Height and width .

Comment: height is 120 for iPhone and 170 for ipad. Width is wing calculated but its same for all screen size

Comment: are u getting any `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints` log messages .?

Comment: Yes. I am getting this in log.

Comment: instead of this topImageView(>=120,<=170) .. topImageView(>=120,<=1024) .. or bigger than 540 will do ..

Comment: But how will it set height as 170 in iPad.

Comment: so u want height of image to 170 on iPad and 120 on iPhone ..

Comment: That view is adde by code or by xib?

Comment: Yes I want height of image to 170 on iPad and 120 on iPhone.

Comment: It is added through code.

Comment: @Nitish :  -(BOOL)isIpad{if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {return FALSE;}else{return TRUE;}}
isIpad just for height .. use NSLayoutConstraint for width

Comment: Yes Rahul. I have to place a condition for this. Thanks